# Python RegEx: How to conditionally match multiple optional ending characters in a URL

Tags: python, django, regex

I have to match URLs in my Django *re_path* function.

The structures to be matched are as follows:

1. Any URL must start with an optional `/user` string followed with a `/profile` part
2. After that, there should be either `/`, other URL subparts, or end of string

Here below the examples for allowed URLs:

- /profile
- /profile/
- /profile/asd
- /profile/asd/
- /user/profile
- /user/profile/
- /user/profile/asd
- /user/profile/asd/
- /user/profile/asd/blah

I tried the following, but it fails:

```
re_path(r'^profile/?.*$', views.my_view)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Last allowed URLs is not fit to your second rule. It starts with `/user/profile` but not ends with `profile`, or `profile/` or `profile/blabla`

Comment: Actually it is, because I meant "asd/" with "blabla".

Comment: If that, you should explain which character blabla should have. It is likely `/user/profile/?!#` or `/user/profile/1/2/3` can also be possible.

Comment: For example, I failed when I applied your suggestion below for the following:
```profile/xxx/yyy``` (but of course, it works for ```profile/xxx/```). I should be able to extend it whatever the input is, like ```profile/xxx/yyy/zzz/...```

Comment: You were right, I should have explained it better.

Comment: I did not suggested to you. Maybe you think I am answerer. I suggest you first time to use `^/(?:user/)?profile/?.*$` if blabla means all chracters. It is combination of answerer's(first rule) and yours(second rule).

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. Thanks for your input, which exactly matches my needs.

Comment: IMHO, `^/(?:user/)?profile/?.*$` is not quite precise since this willalso match `/user/profiler/...`. You seem to want `^/(?:user/)?profile(?:/.*)?$`

Comment: If my above comment is what you need, I can help you fix the question.

Comment: You are totally right about the problem. It will also match even if there are wrong characters after "profile". It would be great if you help me to fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^/(?:user/)?profile(?:/.*)?$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N9J8bH/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?:user/)?` - an optional `user/` string
- `profile` - a fixesd string
- `(?:/.*)?` - an optional sequence of a `/` char and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you for your input Wiktor! Why I cannot directly use `.*` at the end for optional any character?

Comment: @bbasaran Because you(same as me) think `/?.*` as sub part after `/` like `profile/test` but `/?` is also optional. So `profiler/test` is also possible as Wiktor explained. So Wiktor limited optional chacter to start with `/`.